# Re-format date and time in R

Tags: r, date, time, reformatting

I have two columns of data (both dates), and I need to find the number of days in between (basically the difference between the columns).

One of the columns is formatted like this (imported from SPSS) - I only included two rows as example:
12-Mar-2020 15:51:32
06-Apr-2019 17:08:03

What I need this to look like:

1. I need a new column that doesn't have the time, and it only includes the dates (i.e. get rid of 15:51:32 and 17:08:03).
2. I need to reformat the dates as numbers in the order of year-month-date so that it matches the format of my other column (i.e. I need Mar to become 03 and Apr to 04, in addition to changing the order).

I tried using lubridate package, but it was not successful because of how this column is formatted (in case it's helpful, the class of this column is currently "character").
Please note: My data set is quite big, so I appreciate a solution that works on the entire column at once.

I would appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
as_date(dmy_hms(c("12-Mar-2020 15:51:32", "06-Apr-2019 17:08:03")))
```

Result

```
[1] "2020-03-12" "2019-04-06"
```